# Docker compose build copy failed

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am really curious to how to interpret and debug with the following error:-

```
C:\users\project>docker-compose build 

Step 6/15 : COPY *.csproj ./
ERROR: Service 'invoiceservice' failed to build: COPY failed: no source files were specified
```

This is particular micro-service as i have few more such services.

docker file :-

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime:2.2 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore -s https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json -s https://www.myget.org/F/autoweb/api/v3/index.json

COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/src/InvoiceManagement/InvoiceService
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

FROM build AS publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "InvoiceService.dll"]
```

Interesting part is when I build this from Visual Studio IDE, its being built fine but it does not build on CLI.

docker compose file:-

```
invoiceservice:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}invoiceservice
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: src/InvoiceManagement/InvoiceService/Dockerfile
```

I don't understand why CLI could not find the source location and copy where as VS works fine. Any clue???

Answer (score 3):

It's likely an issue with your Docker context. Commands in Dockerfiles are relative to *where the `docker`/`docker-compose` CLI tool is run*, not relative to the Dockerfile location.

In other words, if you run the command from the solution root, then your csproj file is actually under `./src/InvoiceManagement/InvoiceService`. As a result, `*.csproj` finds no files, because there's no project files literally in your solution root.

Answer (score 0):

I tried replicating your problem and I was able to copy all the files successfully (instead of `.csproj`, I used `.txt`). The problem occurred when there was no `txt` file to copy. My COPY command failed with exactly the same message as yours.

Now, why is VS able to build the image successfully? That is because VS build the project first! When the project's build procedure is completed, a `.csproj` file is generated and that gets copied to the image.

To confirm the results, `ls` your current directory (when the build fails from command line) and see if there is any `.csproj` file in that directory.

Comment: Sorry I don't get your point here! used .txt what do you mean by .txt since VS project file is csproj and it has all the configurations therefore where does .txt come from and all the dockerfile settings I never seen any such .txt instead of csproj file. Can you elaborate it more precisely..

Comment: @Urgen Instead of using `COPY *.csproj ./`, I used `COPY *.txt ./` because I do not have a C# project with me right now. That's all I meant.

Comment: @Urgen Let me know if it fixes the problem and consider accepting the answer if it does.